# Android Retrofit Json Parsing(part of json dynamic)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

We are using Retrofit 1.9

Initially server was returning a json like this-

```
{
"known_key1":"value1",
"known_key2":"value2"
}
```

We had created Model -

```
public class ResponseModel {
    @SerializedName("known_key1")
    private String knownKey1;

    @SerializedName("known_key2")
    private String knownKey2;
}
```

Everything was working fine.

but now server is returning some more keys in the response, but the keys are dynamic -

```
{
"known_key1":"value1",
"known_key2":"value2",
"dynamic_key1":"value1",
"dynamic_key2":"value2"
}
```

Now what should be our Model ?

Comment: in that case, don't use model.Instead use JsonObject and parse keys from the JsonObject.

Comment: You mean we need to parse it manually ?

Comment: yep or you can use a Map<String,Object> as @Mike suggested

Answer (score 0):

For instances like this you can use maps

`Map<String, Object> map`

Comment: If we include like this in Model, how Gson will deserialize it, I mean to what key Gson will assign. we are not getting any key as map.

Comment: No you don't need the model anymore, just go straight map. So when parsing the response its as simple as key value pair.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Instead of using the ResponseModel class, just use the Map<String, Object>

Comment: Thank you Mike. It works, but if we go with this approach all my json key and values will be in Map. Its ok. But our json response has around 45 keys and some of them are mapping to Custom Object. Basically We want to have Model with corresponding data. Can we achieve this ?

Comment: Of course, but you will have to customize a class based on Map and do adjustments needed to fit the responses of your app. You can also try generic types <T> although I use this on Retrofit 2.1.0 I think it should work.